# php script giving timeout or blank page after server update

Tags: php

I have a script that calculates biorythm and shows a graph with a result. 
For an unknown to me reason, the following script does not seem to work after the server has been updated.

```
<?php
    $now = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT';
    header('Expires: ' . $now);
    header('Last-Modified: ' . $now);
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    error_reporting(0);

    $copyright = "By www.magnaromagna.it";


    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $day = $_POST["day"];
    $month = $_POST["month"];
    $year = $_POST["year"];
    $cycle = $_POST["cycle"];
    $chartsize = $_POST["chartsize"];

    $name = strip_tags($name);
    if($chartsize == "small")
    {
      $chartwidth = 450;
      $chartheight = 252;
      $tablewidth = 500;
    }
    elseif($chartsize == "medium")
    {
      $chartwidth = 625;
      $chartheight = 350;
      $tablewidth = 655;
    }
    else
    {
      $chartwidth = 800;
      $chartheight = 448;
      $tablewidth = 820;
    }


    $date = date("m/d/y");
    function drawRhythm($daysalive, $period, $color)
    {
        //$period = $period * 2;
        global $cycle, $image, $chartwidth, $chartheight;


        $centerday = $daysalive - ($cycle / 2);
        $plotscale = ($chartheight - 25) / 2;
        $plotcenter = ($chartheight - 25) / 2;

        // draw the curve
        for($count = 0; $count <= $cycle; $count++  )
        {

    echo    $date ; 
            $phase = ((($centerday) + $count) % $period) / $period * 2 * pi();
            $y = 1 - sin($phase) * (float)$plotscale  + (float)$plotcenter;

            if($count > 0)
            {
                imageLine($image, $oldx, $oldy, $count * $chartwidth / $cycle, $y, $color);
            }
            $oldx = $count * $chartwidth / $cycle;
            $oldy = $y;
          }

    }

    $pastdays = abs(gregorianToJD($month, $day, $year) - gregorianToJD(date( "m"), date( "d"), date( "Y")));

    $image = imageCreate($chartwidth, $chartheight);

    $colorbackground   = imageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $colorforeground   = imageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $colorgrid         = imageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $colorborder       = imageColorAllocate($image, 175, 175, 175);
    $colorcross        = imageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $colorphysical     = imageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 255);
    $coloremotional    = imageColorAllocate($image, 255, 0, 0);
    $colorintellectual = imageColorAllocate($image, 0, 255, 0);
    $colorintuitive    = imageColorAllocate($image, 255, 0, 255);
    $colorawareness    = imageColorAllocate($image, 255, 125, 0);
    $colorspiritual    = imageColorAllocate($image, 0, 255, 255);
    $coloraesthetic    = imageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 0);

    imageFilledRectangle($image, 0, 0, $width - 1, $height - 1, $colorbackground);


    $nrsecondsperday = 60 * 60 * 24;
    // add a + before $nrsecondsperday; //
    $diagramdate = time() - ($cycle / 2 + $nrsecondsperday) * $nrsecondsperday;
    $flagcount = 1;
    for ($index = 1; $index < $cycle; $index  )
    {
        $thisdate = getDate($diagramdate);
        $countCoord = ($chartwidth / $cycle) * $index;


        imageLine($image, $countCoord, $chartheight - 25, $countCoord, $chartheight - 20, $colorgrid);

        $flag = $flagcount%2; 

        if($cycle == 60 && $flag == 0)
        {
          imageString($image, 3, $countCoord - 2, $chartheight - 16, $thisdate[ "mday"], $colorgrid);
        }
        elseif($cycle != 60)
        {
          imageString($image, 3, $countCoord - 5, $chartheight - 16, $thisdate[ "mday"], $colorgrid);
        }
        $flagcount  ;
        $diagramdate  = $nrsecondsperday;
    }


    imageRectangle($image, 0, 0, $chartwidth - 1, $chartheight - 20, $colorborder);

    imageLine($image, 0, ($chartheight - 20) / 2, $chartwidth, ($chartheight - 20) / 2, $colorcross);
    imageLine($image, $chartwidth / 2, 0, $chartwidth / 2, $chartheight - 20, $colorcross);

    drawRhythm($pastdays, 23, $colorphysical);
    drawRhythm($pastdays, 28, $coloremotional);
    drawRhythm($pastdays, 33, $colorintellectual);
    drawRhythm($pastdays, 38, $colorintuitive);
    drawRhythm($pastdays, 43, $coloraesthetic);
    drawRhythm($pastdays, 48, $colorawareness);
    drawRhythm($pastdays, 53, $colorspiritual);

    $subnum = rand(0, 999999);
    $subnum = "images/dummies/".$subnum.".gif";
    imageGIF($image,$subnum);
    imagedestroy($image);
    ?>

    <html>

    <head>
    <title>Risultato Bioritmo</title>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="biostyle.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div align="center"><center>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0"  width="90%">
    <TR><TD align = "right"><a href="http://www.magnaromagna.it/bioritmo/" target="_blank" class="pagelinks">Calcola altro bioritmo</a>
      </TD></TR></TABLE>
    </div>
    <div align="center"><center>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0"  width="90%" class="outertable">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="genericstyle"><p class="bluesubheader">
        <?php
           if($name != "")
           {
             echo "Bioritmo per $name<br>";
           }
           else
           {
              echo "Mappa dei tuoi bioritmi<br>";
           }
         ?>

        <?php
           echo "Nascita: $month/$day/$year<br>Data di oggi: $date";
        ?>
        </p>
        <p align="center"><img src="<?php echo "$subnum"; ?>">
            Rosso: Ciclo Emozionale&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            Blu: Ciclo Fisico&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            Verde: Ciclo Intelligenza <br>
            Viola: Intuito&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            Acqua: Ciclo Spirituale&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            Giallo: Ciclo Estetico&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            Arancione:Ciclo Consapevolezza</p>
        <p align="left"><span class="bluesubheader"><br>
        Capire il tuo bioritmo</span></p>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </center></div>
    <div align="center"><center>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0"  width="90%">
    <TR><TD align = "right"><a href="http://www.magnaromagna.it/bioritmo/" class="pagelinks" target="_blank">Calcola altro bioritmo</a>
      </TD></TR></TABLE>
    </div>
    <div align="center"><center>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" width="300">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="copyright">Copyright Magnaromagna</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </center></div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php include("images/dummies/cleanup.php"); ?>
```

After executing it, the following happens:

> The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application

Its either that or the script results in a blank page.

I don't think that server should take that much time in an execution of this script, but then again it might be just my coding fault.

- An example of timeout is the execution here:
  http://tuttoblog.com/bioritmo/   (just insert a random name and year and execute)
- An example of a blank page would be the execution here: 
  http://magnaromagna.it/bioritmo/   (just insert a random name and year then execute)

Any help in the matter would be immensely appreciated since I'm pretty short on time.

My phpinfo -> magnaromagna.it/phpinfo.php

Comment: Try increasing your `max_execution_time` -- does that solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting:

```
set_time_limit(300);
```

At the top of your page, before the rest of your PHP code. See if your script will execute properly then - you should aim to reduce the amount of time the script takes to execute though, even if that does solve it.

Edit: I have a feeling that won't work, as it might not be PHP that's having a problem with timing out. If that doesn't help, then it's probably something to do with how your server is set up and you'll need to fix that, or get someone else to do so.